# TypeScript type inference is broken on my machine

Tags: angular, typescript

My team just switched to macs and when I pulled down the code from our repo I'm getting tons of type errors, exclusively in the template. Namely "Object is of type 'unknown'."

Here is a specific example of some problem code:
<ng-container *ngIf="viewModel$ | async as vm">

Where vm should be getting assigned the type of 'example' it says that it is 'unknown'. The rest of my team with the exact same code sees the type correctly as 'example'. So where we have code that's accessing the properties of the 'example' class i'm getting that Object is of type 'unknown' error.

I have tried deleting node modules and running npm i, recloning, deleting and reinstalling angular & vs code. My version of angular, typescript etc. match the rest of my teams.

Changing strictCheck to false in the tsconfig does fix the issue and allows me to build but it is obviously not a very long term solution.

Comment: When you say your version of Typescript is same, are referring to the version from `package.json`?

Comment: Upon running ng-version all of our Typescript versions are 4.9.5. I see that it's also in the package.json

Comment: Could you once run `npm ls typescript ` to see what's in the `node_modules`?

Comment: Everything said 4.9.5 besides this line



├─┬ prettier-eslint@13.0.0
│ └── typescript@3.9.10
└── typescript@4.9.5

Comment: That's really strange. Unfortunately it won't be possible for anyone to debug it without reproducing it. Things that you can try are restart typescript server, make sure you're using the same IDE & linter as before and restart your IDE. I think you've probably tried all of that already.